# Dynamically replace white space with underscores in column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to dynamically replace the white space in my column names with underscores.  I have written the following code so far, however, this code updates the new column name with the actual REPLACE statement as a string as opposed to replacing it as a function:

```
select b.column_id,b.name
into #container2
from sys.tables a
join sys.columns b
    on a.object_id = b.object_id
where a.name = 'my_table'

declare @id int
declare @columnName varchar(255)
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @id = 1
select @columnname = name from #container2 where column_id = @id

while @id <= 73
begin

    set @sql = 'EXEC sp_RENAME ''db.my_table.[' + @columnName + ']'', ''REPLACE([' + @columnName + '], '''' '''', ''''_'''')'', ''COLUMN''' 
    print @sql
    --exec(@sql)

    set @id = @id + 1
    select @columnname = name from #container2 where column_id = @id
end
```

I have tried moving my REPLACE statement outside of my new column string, but that errors out.

My expected outcome is:

```
old column name: Apple Pie
new column name: Apple_Pie
```

Comment: You should not concatenate the replace call, it should run at the SET @sql variable level. So the call to the sp_RENAME will receive the old name and the new name instead of the old name and a call to the replace function

Comment: you should not use dynamic SQL at all here. the call to `EXEC sp_RENAME` doesn't need to be inside a dynamic SQL string

Comment: @MartinSmith I assumed that he filtered (`my_table`) the query on `sys.tables` as a test, he probably want this to run on all tables on his database

Comment: No, I just want to run it on one table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Smith is 100% correct...  even assuming there are many columns to be renamed.

Wholesale changes like this could cause problems, confusion and collisions.

That said, here is a little dynamic SQL that you can execute with caution.   Please NOTE that I am printing the SQL and not executing it.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''

Select @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC sp_rename '''  + quotename(table_name)+'.' + quotename(column_name) +''',''' + replace(column_name,' ','_') + ''';'+char(13) 
  From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  Where charindex(' ',Column_Name)>0
    and table_name = 'SomeDesiredTableName'

Print @SQL
--Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: One question - I'm getting an error that says @itemtype was input as (null). Is there a way around this?

Comment: @thedatasleuth I'm assuming the (at)itemtype was some residual code.  :)